# Datetime diff returning weird output

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using DateTime and diff to compute the difference in days between two dates as follows:

```
$data_inceput = '2013-10-01';
$data_sfarsit = '2013-10-31';
$date1 = new DateTime($data_inceput);
$date2 = new DateTime($data_sfarsit);

$nr_zile = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

`$nr_zile` comes out as 6015 for some reasons.

If I `` `var_dump($date2->diff($date1)); ``

i get:

```
object(DateInterval)#6 (8) {
   ["y"] => int(0)
   ["m"] => int(0)
   ["d"] => int(30)
   ["h"] => int(0)
   ["i"] => int(0)
   ["s"] => int(0)
   ["invert"] => int(1)
   ["days"] => int(6015)
```

Any idea why it's behaving this way? I've also tried to set the timezone to UTC to each date individually and get the same result.

edit: I tested on the production server and it works great, the only problem is on local apache server but the php settings are basically identical between the two.

Comment: Which php version are you using ? I tested this code on PHP 5.3.13 and had no issue ($nr_zile comes out as 30)

Comment: Lemme check. It also works okay for me on the remote server but gives me the above result on my local apache server... even tho the php settings are basically the same

Comment: Have you set the UTC timezone prior to creating the DateTime instances, using `date_default_timezone_set`? If not please do... all the same: the `diff` result is rather weird, but would you care to say what timezone you are in, using `date_default_timezone_get`?

Comment: The date i've set is date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Bucharest"); I tried explicitly setting the same time zone for each individual date as well as setting UCT for the individual dates, same result.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#102507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a problem of Windows https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184

upgrade to the latest php version or use any alternate solution for this.

Comment: yep, this seems to be the problem and I can't just upgrade to the latest php version. Guess I'll have to change the way I calculate date differences.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way you can use:

```
$data_inceput = strtotime('2013-10-01');
$data_sfarsit = strtotime('2013-10-31');
$daysBetween = round(($data_sfarsit - $data_inceput) / 86400);
```

Comment: I ended up using this method even tho there is some possibility for error (mainly with regards to DST) but I don't really mind since I'm only interested in days and not hours and the error isn't cumulative.